# Calculating New Rows based on Multiple Criteria using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df that I'm trying populate a new column based on a calculation. Here is an example below.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {"Quantity" :[4721,1647],
         "Total" : [236.05,82.35]},
        index = [1,2])

df["CPS Gross"]= (df["Total"]/df["Quantity"])

conditions = [df["CPS Gross"] == 0.05]
values = [0.03]

df["CPS Calc"] = np.select(conditions,values)

print(df)
```

Can someone explain to me why the second row does not meet the condition test but the first row does even though they both meet the criteria of 0.05?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: can you provide a few example rows? with the matching expected output?

Comment: row 1 = Quantity = 4721; Total = 236.05

Comment: row 2 = Quantity = 1647; Total = 82.35

Comment: Both of these should equal to 0.05 however in the ws["CPS Calc"] my second row shows up as 0 instead of 0.03

Comment: please don't post code in comments, edit your question

Comment: sorry @mozway first time on here thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I cannot comment your original post so I'll leave you an answer.*

The reason why the second row does not meet the condition is because [floats are not a precise type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/13138364). Despite the real result of the operation 82.35/1647 is 0.05, if you check it on Python you will see that the result it gives is 0.049999999999999996, that is not exactly 0.05. That's the reason why `82.35/1647 == 0.05` is False... because it is really False! (in Python)

One solution you could try is using some method to take in consideration this behaviour like `math.isclose()`. It does not check if two values are exactly the same but if two values are close to each other in a certain range (called *tolerance*).

```
from math import isclose

...

conditions = [ws['New Gross'].apply(lambda x: isclose(x, 0.05, abs_tol=1e-8))]
values = [0.03]

df["CPS Calc"] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

If you check that you will see like now both rows are selected!

Comment: I've used `isclose` in an apply function because `ws[New Gross]` is a Series so you cannot put it in the first param of `isclose` just like that.

Comment: good answer, but note that [`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) should be faster: `conditions = np.isclose(df['CPS Gross'], 0.05)`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `np.select` function with the `np.where` function as it can have a singular value as input:

```
ws["CPS Calc"] = np.where(ws["New Gross"]==0.05,0.03,np.nan)
```

The last value is the default when the condition is not true (I assumed it to be NaN but can be any value).

Comment: I'm confused as to why the second row in my example fails to meet the conditions I've set. Can you explain to me why the second row fails the condition but the first one passes?

Comment: When I run `np.select` with your values I get `ValueError: list of cases must be same length as list of conditions`. It's exactly as I said: `np.select` selects values from an array according to a list of conditions. You are selecting values from a single array so of course it wouldn't work.

Comment: Hey can you take another look at the question? Sorry i don't think i was clear the first time around. That code in the question should not error out

Comment: Ok, next time please provide the values in the question to help us answer it, although I think @rmoret has answered your question.